# Qt Test output in TeamCity

Tags: c++, qt, testing, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there any possible to analyse output of Qt Test framework in TeamCity build server (e.g. from xml file or using [Cpp Unit Testing plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Cpp+Unit+Test+Reporting))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Qt 5.7.0, there is a `-teamcity` option that reports the testresults in the teamcity format. See [Qt Test Overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#logging-options) for more informations.